# select field height in bootstrap form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

size of the select field is affecting by a bootstrap file as shown in the screenshot and i'm unable to find out how to solve this problem.

```
    <form>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name" class="labstyle">Enter Your Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" size="20" 
        maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter You Name" required autofocus>
       </div>
           <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sell" class="labstyle">Chose Your Wish:</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="sell">
       <option value="0" hidden="hidden" disabled="" selected="">Chose Your 
        Wish</option>
       <option value="morning">Good Morning</option>
        <option value="night">Good Night</option>
     </select>
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="message" class="labstyle">Message</label>
         <textarea class="form-control"  name="message" rows="3" cols="40" 
    placeholder="Optional" maxlength="92"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btncustom">Create</button>
     </form>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you talking about the word inside the select? I've realized that it's cutting the letters.

Comment: yes that's the problem it's cutting the letter please help me to solve this problem

Comment: have `height` equal to `line-height`

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following will calculate correctly the height in this situation.

```
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
  height: auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

include this in abc.component.ts

```
styles: [`
:host /deep/ select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
  height: auto!important;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}`]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, inside your custom `select.form-control` class, try to decrease the `line-height` property for something like that:

```
line-height: 1.0;
```

or maybe a small value.

Comment: it's not working  the whole problem is this
 select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this custom style?

Comment: Ok, why do you included this custom class? Can you remove (comment) this class and send a screenshot?

Comment: it only include color
 .labstyle {
      color:#bcbdc0;
      }

Answer (score 0):

**Add this class in your custom style sheet (css file).**

```
.form-control{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

include this on your css it will fix the problem

```
#sell.form-control{
height: 46px important!;
}
```

Comment: remove the <pre> tags

Comment: [edit] your answer and remove `<pre>` tag yourself. Please check [answer]